# Is this code's running time Big Theta (n^2)?

Tags: java, performance, time-complexity, big-o

```
public int calculateValue(int i, int j) {
    int count = 0;
    for(int r = 0; r < i; r++){
        for(int c = 0; c < j; c++){
            if(A[r][c] == 1){
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

I have been trying to figure out if this code is running on Big Theta of n^2. I am certain it is O(n^2), but I am not sure if it is Big Omega of (n^2). Is there a simple way to determine this?

Note: the input array A is a simple 2D array of size n x n.

Comment: What's `n`? Your code makes no reference to such a value. So in terms of variable `n` it may very well be O(1).

Comment: I apologise. This is part of a question for university. The input array is defined to be n x n.

Answer (score 3):

The cost should be expressed in terms of *i* and *j*, since those are the input variables.

- The outer loop runs for *i* iterations, the inner loop for *j* iterations.
- Their iteration counts are independent of each other.
- Assuming that *A* is simple 2-D array, the cost of the inner loop body is *Θ*(1).

Given these conditions, it is safe to multiply their costs together. Therefore the overall runtime is *Θ*(*ij*).

Comment: Since it is tagged as java, the assumption that A is a simple 2D array is pretty good.

Comment: @matt looks more like a jagged array in terms of syntax.  But i think that is irrelevant, just nit picking by me.

Comment: It is a simple 2D array.

Comment: I should have posted the entire class, but regardless. The value of n is defined as the size of the input array. A is a 2D array of size n x n.

Comment: @CSharpie java only has one array syntax.

Comment: @EnzoBestetti The size of the array has nothing to do with the number of calculations here.

Comment: even if the array is a jagged one, the loop condition will not change, still `i*j` iterations (or an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`)

Comment: Are we certain that the size of the array is entirely irrelevant? Meaning, if i and j can be at worst equal to n, the worst case running time is O(n²) is it not?

Comment: "Meaning, if i and j can be at worst equal to n" @EnzoBestetti  That is pretty good logic. So you're right there is an implicit constraint where i and j cannot be greater than n, which gives you n^2. Without any extra information you're correct.